# Botium CLI tests for rasa chatbot passing for any random convo (that should not pass)

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I'm trying to setup Botium CLI with my rasa chatbot for automated integration testing and dialog flow tests. However, the botium framework passes tests that do not describe a conversation flow that would be possible with my chatbot.

I'm using it with [botium-connector-rasa](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-rasa) and this is my botium.json config file:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "change me later",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "rasa",
      "RASA_MODE": "DIALOG_AND_NLU",
      "RASA_ENDPOINT_URL": "http://localhost:8080/"
    },
    "Sources": {},
    "Envs": {}
  }
}
```

When I try to run botium-cli pointing --convos to my folder with the .convos.txt files, it passes the tests even if they should have failed.

.convo.txt file:

```
Test case 02: Robots' hell

# me
random question

# bot
random answer
```

Command used for running the tests:

```
botium-cli run --config botium.json --convos ./convos/
```

The output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3OZ1.png)

What is going on? Why is botium passing my random tests when it should've failed these tests?

I've tried to talk with the bot using the emulator and if i run *botium-cli emulator* it works properly and I can communicate with my chatbot as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the .convo.txt files' syntax.
I just had to remove the spaces between the **#** and the **me**/**bot**. The provided example convo should look like this instead:

```
Test case 02: Robots' hell

#me
random question

#bot
random answer
```